# jQuery Animate Header on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scrolltop

I'm building a simple header for a plain HTML5 site. I'm trying to make the header change background color at a certain `.scrollTop()`. I know the `scroll` part is working, just not the animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var SCROLL = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(SCROLL > 100) {
            $('header#header').animate({
                background:'#fff'
            },300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you share the html? Are you using header tag or an element with id header or both?

Comment: I'm using both. @prem89

Comment: Ok share the HTML or create a jsfiddle

Comment: You can animate on scrol... Read the docs...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Micky_Munns/gmv53qa4/ @prem89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using just jQuery, please remember that you need external plugins to animate your background color only with jQuery.

Please check fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3dis/L06dcg4c/

I used this plugin:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

**But.**

I offer you to use CSS3 transitions and jQuery **addClass, removeClass**.

Example:

```
if(SCROLL > 100) {
            jQuery('header').addClass('white');
        } else if(SCROLL < 100) {
            jQuery('header').removeClass('white');
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3dis/L06dcg4c/1/